# How can one "look dead" and "approach happily" at the same time? I think this textbook answer is wrong

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I answered B but it says the correct answer is C.

How can she "LOOK DEAD" at the same time approaching HAPPILY?

Both are the conditions of her status.

This is the relevant text from the test, which is about manatees:

> They are friendly and sometimes approach boats without caution. In 1989, a female manatee named Marjorie was captured in Coot Bay. She looked dead. Her belly was badly torn by the propeller of a motorboat. Rescued immediately, she was transported to Miami Seaquarium and treated with great care.

These are the answer choices:

> **A** The statement is patently TRUE or follows logically, given the information or opinions contained in the passage.
> **B** The statement is patently UNTRUE or the opposite follows logically, given the information or opinions contained in the passage.
> **C** You CANNOT SAY whether the statement is true or untrue, or follows logically without further information.

This is the statement to evaluate as A, B or C:

> Marjorie happily approached the boat, and was badly injured.

Comment: Didn't you already ask the same question earlier today?  https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/327459/i-think-these-textbook-answers-are-wrong

Comment: This newer question is the best version of the question, because it explains why you do not agree with the answer. In my opinion, the older question should be closed or deleted.

Comment: I've deleted the other one as this one is better.

Comment: Your manatee was *captured*.  There is nothing in the passage suggesting she, like the manatees that sometimes approach boats, approached the boat.  She may have but we don't know.  Answer C.

Comment: The other one had one other question that was solved.. But this post focused on this question that didn't get focused on the other. Thanks EllieK, that helps too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are apparently confused about the time sequence.

First, the word "and" can mean that two things happened simultaneously or are true simultaneously. Like if I say, "Sally has red hair and green eyes", I almost surely mean that she has both of these things at the same time. But "and" can also be used to link events in a sequence. In this case, "Marjorie happily approached the boat and was badly injured" means that first she happily approached the boat, and then after that she was badly injured.

But in any case, she didn't "look dead" until after all of that happened. She happily approached the boat. Then she was badly injured by the boat's propeller. Then, later, she was found looking dead.

Thus, the correct answer is not B. There is no contradiction between saying that she was badly injured and then at some later time looked dead.

The correct answer is not A because, at least as far as the text tells us, no one saw her get injured so no one knows exactly how it happened. And presumably as manatees can't speak English she couldn't tell us. She MIGHT have happily approached a boat and been injured. Or she might have been injured in some other way.

Thus the correct answer is C.

Comment: +1 With a quibble: the fact that the text doesn't tell us how she got injured is all that matters. Everything else about witnesses and speaking English is a confusing distraction. Even if the text told us that people saw the whole thing happen and that Marjorie is a native speaker of English, the text doesn't tell us how the injury happened.

Comment: Thanks so much, Jay. This clarified why the answer is correct. I initially thought that the question was asking if she approached the "rescue boat" happily and looked badly injured at the same time. But it was actually asking if she approached the "unknown boat" happily, then looked badly injured to the "rescue boat".

Comment: @se678, umm, what rescue boat?  :-)  It seemed like that to me too at first read, but Marjorie was simply *captured* in the bay and rescued.  She could have been found floating on the shallows near the shore with her near-dead pallor.  The question says 'approached *the* boat' - there was only one.

Comment: @mcalex She may have been picked up by a "rescue boat", or she may have washed up on a beach, or some other circumstances. Likewise she may have been injured by an encounter with a boat or in some other way. The story doesn't say, and probably no one knows. There may have been no boats involved, one, two, or who knows, maybe more. That's why the correct answer is C. From the information given, we don't know the details.

Comment: @Jay There was (at least) one boat involved in the encounter - the story **does** say:  'Her belly was badly torn by the propeller of a motorboat.'  My point was that there is no evidence to _assume_ a rescue boat exists, which se678 appears to have done.

Comment: @mcalex "At least one boat" True. I was thinking that they said that some manatees are injured by boat propellors but didn't explicitly say this one was, but on re-reading, I see they did. Anyway, the point is, she MIGHT have been picked up by a boat. She MIGHT have floated onto the beach. We don't know, the story doesn't say.

Comment: @Jay Which is pretty much what I said to se678 at the beginning (though I must have deleted the final word 'mentioned' that I definitely typed).